# How to change the background colour based on a condition of a column in Unix

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file with below content:

```
<tr><td>CLNK </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115061</td><td> 9965
<tr><td>CLNM </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-JK-00 </td><td> 841115062</td><td> 9976
<tr><td>CLNKHGKSL </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115063</td><td> 9985
<tr><td>CLNK </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-CRD-N-TR-00 </td><td> 841115064</td><td> 9925
<tr><td>CLNK00 </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-CCS-N-HJ-00 </td><td> 841115065</td><td> 9905
<tr><td>CLNKTYH </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115066</td><td> 9915
<tr><td>CLNKVB </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-MN-00 </td><td> 841115067</td><td> 9935
<tr><td>CLN </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-PLN-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115068</td><td> 9955
<tr><td>CLNK1 </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115069</td><td> 9970
```

I want the below output based on 5th column value, if 5th field value is >9960 then it will replace  part with below string

```
<tr><td>CLNK </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115061</td><td bgcolor="red"> 9965
<tr><td>CLNM </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-JK-00 </td><td> 841115062</td><td bgcolor="red"> 9976
<tr><td>CLNKHGKSL </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115063</td><td bgcolor="red"> 9985
<tr><td>CLNK </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-CRD-N-TR-00 </td><td> 841115064</td><td> 9925
<tr><td>CLNK00 </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-CCS-N-HJ-00 </td><td> 841115065</td><td> 9905
<tr><td>CLNKTYH </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115066</td><td> 9915
<tr><td>CLNKVB </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-MN-00 </td><td> 841115067</td><td> 9935
<tr><td>CLN </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-PLN-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115068</td><td> 9955
<tr><td>CLNK1 </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115069</td><td bgcolor="red"> 9970
```

Comment: Your HTML does not seem well formed. Also I would not recommend `bgcolor="red"` instead you should used a class, and do the colour in css. Also there in not 5th field, it only goes up to 4.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It's incomplete, but it's well-formed (`<td>`s don't need a closing tag in html4/5). As to the OP, they would be better served by slapping a `<script>
for(let td of document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(4)')) if(td.textContent > 9960) td.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
</script>` just after the end of the table ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If we can safely assume that the value you are interested in is always the last stretch of numbers on each line (as is the case in your example), you can do:

```
$ perl -pe 'm|.*(<td>\s*(\d+)\s*(</td>)?\s*)$|; 
            $cell=$1; 
            $value=$2; 
            if($value > 9960){
                s|$cell|<td bgcolor="red">$value</td>\n|
            }' file 
<tr><td>CLNK </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115061</td><td bgcolor="red">9965</td>
<tr><td>CLNM </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-JK-00 </td><td> 841115062</td><td bgcolor="red">9976</td>
<tr><td>CLNKHGKSL </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115063</td><td bgcolor="red">9985</td>
<tr><td>CLNK </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-CRD-N-TR-00 </td><td> 841115064</td><td> 9925
<tr><td>CLNK00 </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-CCS-N-HJ-00 </td><td> 841115065</td><td> 9905
<tr><td>CLNKTYH </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115066</td><td> 9915
<tr><td>CLNKVB </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-MN-00 </td><td> 841115067</td><td> 9935
<tr><td>CLN </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-PLN-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115068</td><td> 9955
<tr><td>CLNK1 </td><td>TR-HEH-JFGHG-MTG-N-US-00 </td><td> 841115069</td><td bgcolor="red">9970</td>
```